# SecurityException android

Tags: android, android-permission

Quando executo no Android Studio o código abaixo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LocationManager lcmanager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    List<String> listadeprovider = lcmanager.getAllProviders();
    LocationProvider locationP;
    for(int i = 0; i < listadeprovider.size(); i++)
    {
        locationP = lcmanager.getProvider(listadeprovider.get(i));
        System.out.println("\nPrecisao: " + locationP.getAccuracy() + "\nSuporta Altitude: " + locationP.supportsAltitude() + "\nRecursos: " + locationP.getPowerRequirement() + "\n");
    }

    }

}
```

e recebo a seguinte mensagem de erro informando que eu não adicionei a permissão ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sullyvan.k19treinamentos, PID: 16601
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sullyvan.k19treinamentos/com.example.sullyvan.k19treinamentos.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: "passive" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: "passive" location provider requires ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1599)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1552)
at android.location.ILocationManager$Stub$Proxy.getProviderProperties(ILocationManager.java:1031)
at android.location.LocationManager.getProvider(LocationManager.java:373)
at com.example.sullyvan.k19treinamentos.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
```

sendo que já adicionei essa permissão no Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"/>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

Alguém pode me ajudar com a questão?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O gerenciamento de permissões mudou. Agora é necessário solicitar a permissão ao usuário no momento que ela for necessária. Não mais pelo Android manifest (para as versões novas). Para as versões velhas, deixe no manifest. Então, vou dar um exemplo aqui de como eu checo determinadas permissões em meu app.

```
private Boolean checkHasPermissions(){

        Boolean permissionsOk = false;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            List<String> permissoes = new ArrayList<>();

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissoes.add(android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
            }

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                permissoes.add(android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
            }

            if(permissoes.size() > 0) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissoes.toArray(new String[permissoes.size()]), PERMISSIONS_REQUEST);
            }else{
                permissionsOk = true;
            }
        }else{
            permissionsOk = true;
        }

        return permissionsOk;
    }
```

Verifique a chamada do método estático requestPermissions. O retorno você poderá tratar sobrescrevendo o método onRequestPermissionResult.

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSIONS_REQUEST:
                // se a requisição for cancelada com "back" tratar como não concedida.
                if (grantResults.length > 0) {

                    Boolean allPermissionsAccepted = true;
                    //verificar se tem alguma permissão não concedida
                    for (int i = 0; i < grantResults.length; i++) {
                        if (grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                            allPermissionsAccepted = false;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    if (allPermissionsAccepted) {
                        setResultOkAndClose();
                    } else {
                        startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), RESULT_SETTINGS);
                    }
                }else{
                    startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_SETTINGS), RESULT_SETTINGS);
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado.

Comment: Que bom! Obrigado pelo comentário!

Answer (score -1):

Tente **adicionar** `android:exported="true"` no seu **manifest file** na **activity** que você está a tentar correr